# Preventing fields from being pickled

Tags: python, pickle

I have a class like this:

```
class Something(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._thing_id
        self._cached_thing

    @property
    def thing(self):
        if self._cached_thing:
            return self._cached_thing

        return Thing.objects.get(id=self._thing_id)
```

When pickling objects like this, I'd like to prevent pickling of the `_cached_thing` field, as it's volatile and a specifically in-memory-only implementation.

Is there a way to suggest to Pickle that I only want a subset of my fields to be pickled?

Comment: zope used the convention of not persisting attributes starting with `_v_`. It's might be a good idea to use this convention or similar so it's obvious to the programmer which attributes aren't pickled. It also makes the implementation of `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` simpler and reusable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pickle can be customized in three ways, as described in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances).

- Provide `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods.
- Provide `__getnewargs__`/`__getnewargs_ex__` (and a constructor that takes those args).
- Provide `__reduce__` (and a function to give to `__reduce__` to reverse it).

The first is usually the simplest:

```
class Something(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._thing_id
        self._cached_thing

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self._thing_id
    def __setstate__(self, thing_id):
        self._thing_id = thing_id

    # etc.
```

If you want something more generic, that will pickle all values (including those set by a subclass, or dynamically after creation, etc.) *except* your blacklist, note that the default is "the instance's `__dict__` is pickled", so just filter that:

```
_blacklist = ['_cached_thing']
def __getstate__(self):
    return {k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if k not in self._blacklist}
def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.__dict__.update(state)
```

And please see gnibbler's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991841/preventing-fields-from-being-pickled#comment29764918_19991841) on the question: if you're doing something generic, you should seriously consider coming up with some kind of naming convention instead of putting a blacklist in each class. Any reader who knows or learns the convention will immediately know which properties are "cache" values rather than part of the "real" value, it'll be more obvious how things work, there's less work for you to do in each class, and fewer places to screw things up with a typo…

Comment: Instead of a blacklist, you can choose a naming convention. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @gnibbler: Great suggestion for anyone who's planning on doing this in more than just one or two places.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the special methods `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` to have pickle save customized data for your objects.

[http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.**getstate**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__)

This should get you started:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._thing_id = 0
        self._cached_thing = None
    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            '_thing_id': self._thing_id,
        }
    def __setstate(self, state):
        self._thing_id = state['_thing_id']
```